# Spring security - expireNow() on session does not do anything

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

We are using a "ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy", with the following configuration:

```
    <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                <constructor-arg ref="clusteredSessionRegistryImpl" />
                <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
                <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="false" />
            </bean>
```

When a user logs in, and then logs in for the second time from a different browser - we can see the following code being invoked (as expected):

```
 protected void allowableSessionsExceeded(List<SessionInformation> sessions, int allowableSessions,
        SessionRegistry registry) throws SessionAuthenticationException {
    ...
    leastRecentlyUsed.expireNow();
}
```

The "leastRecentlyUsed" is the actual older session (as expected).
Now, All is well but the fact that this expiration does not kill eventually the older session, the other browser session that should be expired can still use the application in concurrency with the newer session in the other browser. it seems like the process of the actual destruction of the session does not take place.

1) Who\What is responsible of destroying the session?

2) How can we fix this issue?

Comment: The session that is destroyed isn't the `HttpSession` but the internal object used by Spring. You cannot invalidate an `HttpSession` from another request.

Comment: I know, but doesn't expiring the object used by spring should cause the httpSession to be destroyed eventually? (quote from the expiring method signature: ". An "expired" session is removed as soon as possible by a <code>Filter</code>."

Comment: If you configured it that way but you haven't. Your current setup silently closes the session and creates a new one. This is due to the fact that you have set `exceptionIfMaximumExceeded` to `false` which will basically just relogon.

Comment: Thats exaclty what I'm aiming for - silently closing the session and create a new one, problem is the older session is not being closed (http requests with the JSESSIONID of the older session are handled as if its still non-expired), thats my only problem. (the expired session is still active and can use my webapp normally even though it was set to "expired")

Comment: correct and that is how its going to behave. Session A expires Session B and vice-versa. You won't get an error.

Comment: So how can I set the spring configuration to allow re-login over and over and actually invalidating the older sessions (preventing older sessions to be active)? bear in mind using the flag "exceptionIfMaximumExceeded " = true is not good since it doesnt allow users to re-login.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88690/discussion-between-urbanleg-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it turned out to be the browser cache.
See this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471162/spring-security-with-j-spring-security-logout-possibly-not-logging-out-fully)

In my case, I cleared the cache and noticed that the browser that was supposed to be logged out eventually was unable to access the content of my web App.

**Update**

Eventually found out that we use two configurations in our backend for the security context.

I had to make the Session Registry static and call the same instance in both configurations.

```
private static final SessionRegistry SESSION_REGISTRY = new SessionRegistryImpl();
```

Then setup a bean:

```
@Bean
public static SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return SESSION_REGISTRY;
}
```

And finally use the same instance in both configurations:

```
httpSecurity
    ... // you configuration
    .sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(5)
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).and()
```

Hope this helps someone else :)

Comment: Isn't that exactly what happens when I just inject the SessionRegistry interface instead of creating a new instance?